# Fabric JS object scaling

Tags: fabricjs

I have grouped a set of six squares that form a rectangle and placed a set of 12 circles at the vertices onto the canvas.  The first screen shot below shows the unscaled version.  The issue is that the rectangle object height and width do not change as I scale it up or down. See the second screen shot.

I have tried to scale up or down and check the dimensions of the rectangle using two methods

1) canvas._objects
2) canvas.getObjects()

Neither of these objects reflect the new dimensions of the scaled group of squares.  This must be an error in Fabric JS unless someone can suggest a workaround.  Your input is appreciated.

[image: Not Scaled]

[image: Scaled]

Comment: I created groups with multiple squares, scaling, moving, etc. I have no problems like that, can you provide a JSFiddle ? (maybe the problem is with the zoom)

Comment: Also be sure to destroy the group in order to have updated values from: 1) canvas._objects 2) canvas.getObjects(), groups on FabricJs update all the objects inside them.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=yd4DrG28ci

Comment: I am not able to upload the OpenSeaDragon images and JSFiddle has security issues fetching the tiles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use the scaleX/Y factor from the rect object to calculate the stretched height/width.

Comment: If you believe this is the answer, it would be helpful to include code that demonstrates the fix.

Comment: Hey guys thanks for the input. I am working on the fiddle.  I also use the followinf plugin for OpenSeaDragon https://github.com/altert/OpenseadragonFabricjsOverlay